# Programatically removing Strikethrough TextDecoration from code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have problems achieving the following behaviour in my WPF desktop application:

I dynamically create TextBlocks from code behind and insert them into a StackPanel. This works so far. When the user moves the mouse over the TextBlock, a Strikthrough shall be applied to the *textblock*, indicating that the item can be deleted by clicking on it. Again, this still works. When the mouse leaves the *textblock*, the strikethrough shall be removed, and here's where the exception is thrown saying that IsFrozen must be set to false in order to change the TextDecorationCollection object. I wasn't able to figure out how to get around this.

Here's my code:

```
private void HandleAddedSecondaryDxMouseEnter(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    TextBlock tbl = (TextBlock)sender;
    tbl.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
}

private void HandleAddedSecondaryDxMouseLeave(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    TextBlock tbl = (TextBlock)sender;
    tbl.TextDecorations.Remove(tbl.TextDecorations[0]);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bernd

Comment: you can just set it to `null`,   `tbl.TextDecorations = null;`

Comment: You may want to put an answer in and close off this question, if the above comment did what you wanted it to do

Comment: I already tried to, but I have to wait 8 hours until I can answer my own question :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `TextDecorations` to `null`, this will clear the `Strikethrough` decoration from the `TextBlock`

```
private void HandleAddedSecondaryDxMouseLeave(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tbl = (TextBlock)sender;
    tbl.TextDecorations = null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have found the following to work best for me:

```
TextDecorationCollection decs = (TextDecorationCollection)theRTB.Selection.GetPropertyValue( Inline.TextDecorationsProperty );
if (decs.Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0]))
{
    TextDecorationCollection noUnder = new TextDecorationCollection(decs);
    noUnder.Remove(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);  //this is a bool, and could replace Contains above
    theRTB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, noUnder);
}
```

Obviously this is to remove the underline decoration, but I imagine that strikethrough would be no different.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking all over for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code to remove underline for a text range. Same should work for TextBlock as well.

```
TextDecorationCollection textDecorations;
(textRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection).TryRemove(TextDecorations.Underline, out textDecorations);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, textDecorations);
```

Answer (score 0):

The followin code doesn't clear other decorations:

```
TextDecorationCollection newTextDecoration;

if (richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) is TextDecorationCollection currentTextDecoration)
{
    newTextDecoration = new TextDecorationCollection();

    bool found = false;
    foreach (TextDecoration decoration in currentTextDecoration)
    {
        if (decoration == TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0])
            found = true;
        else
            newTextDecoration.Add(decoration);
    }
    if (!found)
        newTextDecoration.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]);
    newTextDecoration.Freeze();
}
else
{
    newTextDecoration = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
}

richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, newTextDecoration);
```